# How to get the value from the element <p>?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is a snippet of the webpage and my python code. I am trying to get the value $2.00 printed.

My code gives me the required HTML elements output but it does not have the values $2.00 or 07/06. Why?

```html
<div class="io_col1_left">
  <p data-quoteapi="price" class="quoteapi-number quoteapi-price">$2.00</p>
  <p class="io_data" data-quoteapi="dateTime">Closed - 07/06</p>
</div>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
import time
import requests
url = 'https://www.localhost/test'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print response

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

soup.findAll('div', class_='io_col1_left')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page dynamically loads content. You can find the API source in the network tab and use that

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
           'Accept' : 'application/json',
           'Referer' : 'https://www.marketindex.com.au/asx/eof'}

r = requests.get('https://quoteapi.com/api/v5/symbols/eof.asx?appID=af5f4d73c1a54a33&averages=1&liveness=delayed', headers = headers).json()
price = r['quote']['price']
time =  r['quote']['time']
print(price, time)
```

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Comment: this helped, thanks a lot :)

I was trying to paste my question in the right manner that is why was deleting the old comments. But thanks for looking into, really appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

`strip()` is remove spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Replace your code :

```
soup.findAll('div', class_='io_col1_left')
```

To :

```
div = soup.find('div', {'class':'io_col1_left'})

price = div.find("p",{'class':'quoteapi-price'})

dateTime = div.find("p",{'class':'io_data'})

print(price.text.strip())
print(dateTime.text.strip())
```

O/P:

```
$2.00
Closed - 07/06
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to **scrape** `$2.00` then I would recommend replacing:

```
soup.findAll('div', class_='io_col1_left')
```

with:

```
soup.find('div', class_='io_col1_left').findNext("p").getText()
```

if you are trying to **scrape** a whole table which has multiple `div`'s I would recommend replacing the line with this one:

```
table_divs = soup.findAll('div', class_='io_col1_left')
for x in table_divs:
    print(x.findNext("p").getText())
```

I hope this helps